# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) Not sure what to do

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a 2.5D game inspired by Drew Conley from youtube but whenever I try to include this JS file this problem shows up and I cant figure out what it means. any help would be appriciated
Picture in Link
[Code Error from Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58nRx.png)

```js
class NPC extends GameObject{
    constructor(config){
        super(config);
        this.movingProgressRemaining = 32;

        this.directionUpdate = {
            "up:": ["y", -1],
            "down:": ["y", 1],
            "left:": ["x", -1],
            "right:": ["x", 1],
        }
    }

    update(state) {
        this.updateposition();
    }




    updateposition(){
        if (this.movingProgressRemaining > 0){
            const[property, change] = this.directionUpdate[this.direction];
            this[property] += change;
            this.movingProgressRemaining -= 1;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you specify exactly which line is throwing the error. Like which line is line 23?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have `:` inside the object keys. `"up:":` should just be `"up":`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar the problem was i had written a : in my directionUpdates

Comment: I would recommend adding this as a comment instead of an answer